# Simple line matching using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, parsing

I have this string stream:

```
"do=whoposted&amp;t=1934067" rel=nofollow>61</A></TD><TD class=alt2 align=middle>5,286</TD></TR><TR><TD id=td_threadstatusicon_1911046 class=alt1><IMG id=thread_statusicon_1911046 border=0 alt="" src="http://url.com/forum/images/statusicon/thread_new.gif"> </TD><TD class=alt2><IMG title=Node border=0 alt=Node src="http://url.com/forum/images/icons/new.png"></TD><TD id=td_threadtitle_1911046 class=alt1 title="http://lulzimg.com/i14/7bd11b.jpg &#10; &#10;Complete name : cool-thread...."><DIV><A id=thread_gotonew_1911046 href="http://url.com/forum/f80/cool-topic-new/"><IMG class=inlineimg title="Go to first new post" border=0 alt="Go to first new post" src="http://url.com/forum/images/buttons/firstnew.gif"></A> [MULTI] <A style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold" id=thread_title_1911046 href="http://url.com/forum/f80/cool-topic-name-1911046/">Cool Topic Name</A> </DIV><DIV class=smallfont><SPAN style="CURSOR: pointer" onclick="window.open('http://url.com/forum/members/u2031889/', '_self')">m3no</SPAN> </DIV></TD><TD class=alt2 title="Replies: 11, Views: 1,554"><DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: right; WHITE-SPACE: nowrap" class=smallfont>Today <SPAN class=time>08:04 AM</SPAN><BR>by <A href="http://url.com/forum/members/u1131830/" rel=nofollow>karetsos</A> <A "
```

The lines I am interested are similar to this:

```
<A style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold" id=thread_title_1911046 href="http://url.com/forum/f80/cool-topic-name-1911046/">Cool Topic Name</A>
```

From here all I am trying to extract are:

```
Thread id: 1911046 (could be from either location in the string)
Thread name: "Cool Topic Name"
Thread link: "http://url.com/forum/f80/cool-topic-name-1911046/"
```

Currently I use this:

```
Regex pattern = new Regex ( "<A\\s+href=\"([^\"]*)\">([^\\x00]*?)\\s+id=thread_title_(\\S+)</A>" );

MatchCollection matches = pattern.Matches ( doc.ToString ( ) );

foreach ( Match match in matches )
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32 ( match.Groups [ 1 ].Value );

    string name = match.Groups [ 3 ].Value;
    string link = match.Groups [ 2 ].Value;

    ...
}
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me fix the pattern to match it. This used to work but it returns 0 matches.

Comment: All three answers are returning two results for me when run against the sample you posted.  That is true in both online utilities you linked to, as well as in a 'real' .NET program.  Maybe the way you are constructing or retrieving the contents of the doc variable is affecting the result, for example removing whitespace or escaping XML markup characters?  Can you edit the code to show how you get 'doc'?  Is the complete source page publicly available on the web?

Comment: Sure I can add more code, but are you sure you are getting 2 matches. I pasted the sample string posted in your comments with this pattern: <A.*thread_title_(\d+) href=\"([^\"]*)\">([^<]*) and it shows 1 match starting from <A and ends with Dynamics In Nature at once, way beyond it's supposed to select. You said this is greedily capturing everything, right? So that's not a problem?

Comment: In my comment I asked you to try the variation <A(?:[^<]*)thread_title_(\d+) href=\"([^\"]*)\">([^<]*).

Comment: Thanks Kim, you are awesome. I must have missed it between all these comments. It seems to show 2 matches. I will try this at home to see if it matches all 20. This time I believe it will, and if so will let you know so I can mark yours as the accepted answer. Cheers.

Comment: I just tried it in real .net, but it returns 0 matches. I don't know what's going on. But the sample text is the same. Here I am sending you a whole page that has 24 matches: http://tinypaste.com/8a4bc Can you please try it in http://regexhero.net/tester/ if after matching these, I still get inconsistent results then I am gonna use some sort of html parser.

Comment: @Joan See ridgrunner's answer. Proof that it works: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=07da5a1b-a082-4c9e-b268-de1e220e247a (you will have to re-paste the sample text).

Comment: Kim thanks that seems to work for sure. It was painful to debug this but yeah this regex works. Thanks again for your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there will be any number of attributes and the `href` attribute always comes after the `id`, and the attributes may or may not have their values within quotes, then this one should do the trick:

```cs
Regex pattern = new Regex(
    @"<A\b             # Begin start tag
    [^>]+?             # Lazily consume up to id attribute
    id\s*=\s*['""]?thread_title_([^>\s'""]+)['""]?  # $1: id
    [^>]+?             # Lazily consume up to href attribute
    href\s*=\s*['""]?([^>\s'""]+)['""]?             # $2: href
    [^>]*              # Consume up to end of open tag
    >                  # End start tag
    (.*?)                                           # $3: name
    </A\s*>            # Closing tag", 
    RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

**Edit:** Fixed the expression which consumed the end portion of the start tag. (Was `[^>]+`)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but returned 0 matches for some reason. Here is a sample of what I tried with: http://codepaste.net/jby4gf

Comment: @Joan - Ok its fixed. (changed one `+` to a `*`) Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Michael Papile's answer works.  Remove the forward slashes (/) from the beginning and end of the pattern that you showed in your last comment.  Forward slashes are pattern delimiters in Ruby - we don't use them in .NET:

```
var rg = new Regex(@"<A(?:[^<]*)thread_title_(\d+) href=""([^""]*)"">([^<]*)");
```

(In an [verbatim string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx) (`@"..."`) you only need to escape double quotes by doubling them up.

**Edit:** corrected pattern added by Richard to use the latest version from comments.  The original pattern did not match the elements properly, but this variation should.  Interestingly, the pattern works whether or not you add the extraneous \ before the quotes, but Richard is correct that it is not needed.

**Edit (again):** You're right, this pattern is not working on the actual page.  Of the three answers, only ridgrunner's returns 24 matches.

Comment: I would have commented on the other answer, but I am a complete newbie with no comment privileges, apparently.

Comment: Thanks it worked but only returned 1 match as opposed to 20 (total instances in my string stream), do you know why?

Comment: I'm not sure. I tried a string with 3 variations on the <a> element in your example, with random text in between, and your code matched all three.

Comment: Thanks for verifying, it returns the last match for me, so the last similar string in the stream. Can you please try it on this one? http://codepaste.net/jby4gf  Lastly I used this pattern: "<A.*thread_title_(\\d+) href=\"([^\"]*)\">([^<]*)"

Comment: Having that example helped.  The pattern is greedily capturing everything between the first instance of "<A" and the last instance of "<".  Try this variation: @"<A(?:[^<]*)thread_title_(\d+) href=\""([^\""]*)\"">([^<]*)".  I added the non-capturing group "(?:[^<]*)" so that the pattern will only match content between a single opening <A> and closing <\A>.

Comment: Thanks Kim I tried your new pattern but it returned 0 matches.

Comment: Also have you guys seen this: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx Didn't work at all, just wanted to try it outside my app.

Comment: This one seems pretty good but says 0 matches on the pattern I got 1 match: http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: Good news guys, ok so it looks like regexhero escapes with @, So don't use quotes in the regex pattern (and in the test text), and use this: <A.*thread_title_(\d+) href=\"([^\"]*)\">([^<]*)      Then it returns 1 match, so same result and we can all see the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I do not program in c# but here is a regex that works in ruby (I guess you guys have \\ to indicate character classes?)

```
/<A.*thread_title_(\d+) href=\"([^\"]*)\">([^<]*)/
```

EDIT
try this one:
`thread_title_(\d+) href=\"([^\"]*)\"\>(.*?)<\/A>`  it matches 2 of them in that pastie thing you did.  If you have to match complicated things in HTML, regexes are not good, you should use a XML/HTML parser

Comment: Thanks man, I am not sure about character classes though, what are those? Like quotes?

Comment: well like \d for numbers etc.  I notice yours has \\d.  In other languages I used \\ usually means escape \.

Comment: regexes are pretty universal though so give that a try and let me know what your output is, I can tweak it if it works differently for you.

Comment: Thanks I see what you mean. But what about the / character in your regex?

Comment: `/<A.*` is probably not going to work if the RegEx parser is in aggressive mode and given that he's getting it from the string stream.

Comment: I just ran it, the match count  is still 0. I used this: @"/<A.*thread_title_(\d+) href=\""([^\""]*)\"">([^<]*)/" Only escaped the quotes, with double quotes.

Comment: yeah sorry should not have put the / in as kimberly said.  Remove the forward slashes they indicate a regex in ruby.  You should not have to double quote, the forward slash should escape the quotes

Comment: Thanks guys it works, but it only matches 1, not 20 which is what the total count in each string stream. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: Thanks Michael, just saw this will try it when I get back home.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it...

```
<a[^>]+thread_title_(?<id>\d+)[^>]+href="(?<link>[^"]*)">(?<name>[^<]*)</a>
```

Some of the other suggestions were a little too greedy and were matching more than one link at a time with your sample text.

One other thing to point out is the `(?<link>` notation, which is a named group.  It matches the same way as a regular group.  But you can then access these groups in C# by their name, or their index.

You can see this in action here...

http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=7855af6f-7774-4a7c-afa2-81c3e24cf496

By the way, use the `.NET` button at the top of Regex Hero to generate C#, and then the quotes will be properly escaped for you.

Comment: Thanks Steve. It seems pretty good. Can you please try it on this one: http://tinypaste.com/8a4bc It returns 0 matches then.